# observers fire on render of dynamic UI when they should not

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, observers

The problem I face is that `observers` linked to dynamically rendered elements seem to fire on `render`, while this is not how I want it to be.

The reason this is a problem, is that the color buttons I'm making are linked to a plot that takes several seconds to render (`plotly` widget)

I added `ignoreInit = T` the `observers` that are created, but they still fire on rendering, unlike normal observers linked to a button build directly in the `UI`

How do I stop the observers linked to the dynamically rendered `colourInput` from firing when the element is rendered?

In the dummy app below the following series of events is recreated in simplified form:
A model spits out a number (simulated by test button in demo app)
Based on this number, a number of colourInput buttons are made
A same number of `observeEvent`s are made for each.

*Not in the dummy app: When the user chooses to change a color, the corresponding group in plots is recolored accordingly*

The test app contains a working static colourInput, and a dynamic part that demonstrates the problem scenario.

**Test app:**

```
library(shiny)
 library("colourpicker")

THECOLORS <- c('#383838', '#5b195b','#1A237E', '#000080', '#224D17', '#cccc00', '#b37400',  '#990000', 
               '#505050',  '#a02ca0',  '#000099', '#2645e0', '#099441', '#e5e500', '#cc8400', '#cc0000', 
               '#737373', '#e53fe5', '#0000FF', '#4479e1',  '#60A830', '#ffff00','#e69500', '#ff0000', 
               '#b2b2b2', '#eb6ceb', '#6666ff', '#d0a3ff', '#9FDA40',  '#ffff7f', '#ffa500', '#ff4c4c')
ui <- fluidPage(      
      h1("WELCOME TO THE TEST APP", style = 'text-align: center; font-weight:bold' ),
    br(), 
    h3("STATIC PART: doesn't fire on startup, great!",  style = 'font-weight:bold'),
    div(colourpicker::colourInput(inputId = 'StaticColor', label = NULL, palette = "limited", allowedCols = THECOLORS, value = THECOLORS[14], showColour = "background", returnName = TRUE), 
    style = " height: 30px; width: 30px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align:center; padding: 0px; display:block; margin-bottom: 10px"),
    br(),
    h3("Dynamic part: fires on render, NOT great!",  style = 'font-weight:bold'),
    actionButton(inputId = 'Tester', label = 'Click me'),
    br(),
    uiOutput('colorbutton')
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

 values <- reactiveValues()
 values$mycolors <- THECOLORS

 observeEvent(input$Tester, { values$NrofButtons <- sample(1:10, 1) })

 observeEvent(values$NrofButtons, { 
  COLElement <-    function(idx){sprintf("COL_button-%s-%d",values$NrofButtons,idx)}

  output$colorbutton <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:values$NrofButtons, function(x) { 
      div(colourpicker::colourInput(inputId = COLElement(x), label = NULL, palette = "limited", allowedCols = values$mycolors, value = values$mycolors[x], showColour = "background", returnName = TRUE), 
      style = " height: 30px; width: 30px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align:center; padding: 0px; display:block; margin-bottom: 10px")  })
  })

  lapply(1:values$NrofButtons, function(x) { observeEvent(input[[COLElement(x)]], { print(input[[COLElement(x)]] )}, ignoreInit = T)  }) # make observer for each button

 })

 observeEvent(input[['StaticColor']], { print(input[['StaticColor']] )}, ignoreInit = T)

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renders should always be by themselves and be data driven, not event driven -- so I've made the render require the number of colors to be defined before rendering. Of course the number of colors aren't defined until the `observeEvent` is fired by clicking the button.

Overall there is still the issue that every time the button is clicked more observers are created for the same ID, working on a way to destroy these automatically on a subsequent click of the tester button.

The key addition was a `ignoreInit = TRUE` in your `observeEvent(input$Tester, {...})` observer.

```
library(shiny)
library("colourpicker")

THECOLORS <- c('#383838', '#5b195b','#1A237E', '#000080', '#224D17', '#cccc00', '#b37400',  '#990000', 
               '#505050',  '#a02ca0',  '#000099', '#2645e0', '#099441', '#e5e500', '#cc8400', '#cc0000', 
               '#737373', '#e53fe5', '#0000FF', '#4479e1',  '#60A830', '#ffff00','#e69500', '#ff0000', 
               '#b2b2b2', '#eb6ceb', '#6666ff', '#d0a3ff', '#9FDA40',  '#ffff7f', '#ffa500', '#ff4c4c')
ui <- fluidPage(      
  h1("WELCOME TO THE TEST APP", style = 'text-align: center; font-weight:bold' ),
  br(), 
  h3("STATIC PART: doesn't fire on startup, great!",  style = 'font-weight:bold'),
  div(colourpicker::colourInput(inputId = 'StaticColor', label = NULL, palette = "limited", allowedCols = THECOLORS, value = THECOLORS[14], showColour = "background", returnName = TRUE), 
      style = " height: 30px; width: 30px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align:center; padding: 0px; display:block; margin-bottom: 10px"),
  br(),
  h3("Dynamic part: fires on render, NOT great!",  style = 'font-weight:bold'),
  actionButton(inputId = 'Tester', label = 'Click me'),
  br(),
  uiOutput('colorbutton')
)


COLElement <- function(idx) sprintf("COL_button-%d", idx)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues(previous_max = 1)

  observeEvent(input$Tester, {
    values$NrofButtons <- sample(1:10, 1)

    # reset counters for all observers
    for (i in seq(values$NrofButtons)) {
      values[[sprintf("observer%d_renders", i)]] <- 0L
    }

    # only initialize incremental observers
    lapply(values$previous_max:values$NrofButtons, function(x) { 
      observeEvent(input[[COLElement(x)]], { 
        # only execute the second time, since the `ignoreInit` isn't obeyed
        if (values[[sprintf("observer%d_renders", x)]] > 0) {
          print(input[[COLElement(x)]] )
        } else {
          values[[sprintf("observer%d_renders", x)]] <- 1L
        }

      }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    }) # make observer for each button

    # record the max
    values$previous_max <- max(values$previous_max, max(values$NrofButtons))
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)


  output$colorbutton <- renderUI({

    req(length(values$NrofButtons) > 0)

    lapply(1:values$NrofButtons, function(x) { 
      div(colourpicker::colourInput(
        inputId     = COLElement(x)
        , label       = NULL
        , palette     = "limited"
        , allowedCols = THECOLORS
        , value       = THECOLORS[x]
        , showColour  = "background"
        , returnName  = TRUE
      )
      , style = " height: 30px; width: 30px; border-radius: 6px;  border-width: 2px; text-align:center; padding: 0px; display:block; margin-bottom: 10px"
      )
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$StaticColor, { 
    print(input$StaticColor )
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: testing it right now, seems to work indeed, also in my more complex app. How is it that making the output outside the observer of the nrofbuttons make so much difference to the behaviour?

Comment: @Mark it doesn't that part was just best practice -- the key (as I've added in the answer) was a `ignoreInit` in that `observeEvent`

Comment: I'm aware to some extend of what you mentioned about the creating new instances, but I have never managed to find a way to solve this, and so far it hasn't created noticeable problems, but you could end up with an enormous pile of observers if you click often (or run the model many times of course). This code design comes from a question I posted over a year ago from another helper here, I recently decided it was time to fix the bug it caused with triggering the plot that uses the color input twice

Comment: @Mark so does this answer solve the specific question you asked? If not, how can I improve it?

Comment: hm strange... I just finished adjusting my real app (putting various dynamic output elements outside the observers that look at the numerical reactiveValue that determines how many of the various elements to make.... And then tested your latest answer once again, seems it fires the printing of colors again as soon as you click the test button, so your answer as is doesn't change the problem it seems

Comment: right, that problem still exists, but "observers fire on render of dynamic UI when they should not" should be fixed, no? I would post a different question with the general problem of observer lifetimes when they're generated dynamically. It is certainly an important question and you probably will get more attention if you frame it properly instead of trying to embed here.

Comment: No I still get the colors printed directly on rendering when you click the button, i.e. the ignore is not doing anything.

Comment: @Mark ah, I misunderstood the question. I think I have resolved your problem now and simultaneously solved the problem with multiple instances of observers. While it doesn't delete unused observers it now only adds additional observers, otherwise it reuses the old ones

Comment: Ah I see how your code minimizes the problem by at least not creating duplicates. I will test tomorrow when I'm back at work. Still believe this must be unintended behaviour by shiny

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170248/discussion-between-mlegge-and-mark).

Comment: did you see my chat messages mlegge?